# Speedbar tag hierarchy in Clojure - organize manually with comments?

Tags: clojure, speedbar, tags

If I run `speedbar` and call `(speedbar-add-supported-extension ".clj")` in `init.el`, then I see my Clojure files in the speedbar, and I can expand them to show the function definitions inside, like this:

[image]

What I don't like is that Emacs is grouping and sorting the tags by alphabetical order. I would prefer to control the sorting and grouping in the file myself, by functional area. I'd like to give the groups titles (maybe with a comment). For example, something like this works in Xcode:

[image]

Leads to hierachy view:

[image]

Is there a way to do this with Emacs and Speedbar?