# sr-speedbar won't open

Tags: speedbar

I used the package installer to install `sr-speedbar`, so I can have the speedbar and editor in a single frame. When I try `M-x sr-speedbar-open`, it opens a second window (with same file), beeps and says `Wrong type argument: stringp, nil` in the minibuffer.

If I set `debug-on-error` to `t`, I see this:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (wrong-type-argument stringp nil)
  set-window-buffer(#<window 148 on study.cljs> nil)
  sr-speedbar-open()
  sr-speedbar-toggle()
  funcall-interactively(sr-speedbar-toggle)
  call-interactively(sr-speedbar-toggle record nil)
  command-execute(sr-speedbar-toggle record)
  ...
```

Emacs version: GNU Emacs 26.1, macOS
sr-speedbar version: 20140914.2339

Any ideas?

Comment: You might need to give a step-by-step recipe (keystroke by keystroke), starting from `emacs -Q` (no init file). But maybe you'll get lucky and someone will recognize the problem and provide a solution.

Comment: Well, this won't solve your problem, however, if you don't have any special reason to use `sr-speedbar`, try neotree. https://github.com/jaypei/emacs-neotree

Comment: Looks promising. Does it do symbols within a file? I just wrote an elisp function to let me group symbols (in speedbar) using comments (https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/48136/speedbar-tag-hierarchy-in-clojure-organize-manually-with-comments)

Comment: I had the same problem and fixed by removing the line ``(setq speedbar-use-images nil)'' in my init.el and restarting emacs. I hope this helps.